# Logical error in the code

Tags: asp.net

Here is all code

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(),"myModalEditStandType", "$('#myModalEditStandType').modal();", true);

using (con)
{
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
    {
        cmd.CommandText = "select formid,formName from FormDetails where Edition_Id=" + Session["Edition_ID"].ToString() + " ";
        cmd.Connection = con;
        con.Open();

        using (SqlDataReader sdr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            chkFormNames.Items.Clear();
            while (sdr.Read())
            {
                ListItem item = new ListItem();

                item.Text = sdr["formName"].ToString();
                item.Value = sdr["FormId"].ToString();

                standName = e.CommandName.ToString();
                txtStandType.Text = standName.ToString();
                txtStandTypeEdit_ModalBox.Text = standName.ToString();

                string[] commandArgs = e.CommandArgument.ToString().Split(new char[] {','});

                chkFormNames.Items.Add(item);

                foreach (var ca in commandArgs)
                {
                    if(ca != null || ca != string.Empty ||ca != "")
                    {
                        FormDetails_ID = ca;
                        if (item.Value == FormDetails_ID)
                        {
                            item.Selected = true;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        con.Close();
    }
}

grdManageStandType.DataBind();
```

Issue in below code:-

```
 if (item.Value == FormDetails_ID)
 {
   item.Selected = true;
 }
```

i had debugged the code and checked. let me explain with the example of the error
Eg:-
StandTypeName      Forms      Edit Stand Type
Co-Exhibitor     1, 2, 4         Edit

StandTypeName is co-exhibitor which contains 3 forms when i am debugging the code for first form which here is 1 is working fine but for second and third form which here is 2, 4 is giving issue

Here

```
 if (item.Value == FormDetails_ID)
{
  item.Selected = true;
}
```

at the time of debugging when it checks for Forms 2, the item.value and FormDetails.ID both contains value =2 but doesn't go inside if loop it directly goes out of loop
This is exactly the issue please do help for it

Comment: If it goes directly outside of the loop it means commandArgs is empty
also: `ca != null || ca != string.Empty` is the same as `!(ca == null && ca == string.Empty)`, in other words, it's always true.

Answer (score 0):

Check the type of `item.Value` and `FormDetails_ID`.

Maybe you can use `equals` instead of `==`

Comment: item is of ListItem type and FormDetails_ID is of string type

Comment: ca != null || ca != string.Empty is not empty not empty

Comment: can you try if (item.Value == ca)

Comment: if(ca != null || ca != string.Empty ||ca != "") remove this condition and check it once..let me know what you are getting

Comment: Tried both as said by  metin bulak and by  Mohan Srinivas but no change in the output, the issue is still same